# CSS resize div that has display: table-cell

Tags: html, css, centering, css-tables

I have a header on my site, and this has a container and three divs.

The heading container is 100px high.
The first div floats to the left and has a width of 150px
The second div floats to the right and has a width of 150px
The third div has another div inside it, and by default resizes to fill the remaining space.

I want the third div to center vertically. When I add display: table-cell and vertical-align: middle the div shrinks to the size of the text. I can only resize the div using a fixed size.

```
<div id="#headingcontainer">
<div class="leftimg">Left</div>
<div class="rightimg">Right</div>
<div class="heading">Content to be centered horizontally and vertically</div>
</div>

#headingcontainer
{
border: none;
border-bottom: 2px solid #8c8cd4;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #000;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

div.heading
{
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 100px;
text-align: center;
width: auto;
}


div.leftimg
{
width: 150px;
float: left;
}

div.rightimg
{
width: 150px;
float: right;
}
```

Can anyone let me know how I can center the middle div without knowing the exact width?

If I take out the display: table-cell from the heading class it is no longer centered vertically but is horizontally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found an answer that works for me.

First a small change to the HTML (two extra divs in the heading):

```
<div id="#headingcontainer">
    <div class="leftimg">Left</div>
    <div class="rightimg">Right</div>
    <div class="heading"><div><div>Content to be centered horizontally and vertically<div></div></div>
</div>
```

Then change to the CSS:

```
#headingcontainer
{
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #8c8cd4;
    background-color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

div.heading
{
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}

div.heading div
{   
    display: table-row;
}

div.heading div div
{   
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This allows the final div contain the text to be both centered vertically and also horizontally. The help came from another Stack Overflow question I found after more searching - 818725.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you're looking for... I changed div.header in the css to have padding on top, removed the table-cell and also set the margin to auto instead of width auto.  See if this is what you were hoping for.  You will have to adjust the padding on top depending on the spacing but this seems like the easiest way to me.

```
#headingcontainer
{
border: none;
border-bottom: 2px solid #8c8cd4;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #000;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

div.heading
{
height: 100px;
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
padding-top:40px;
}


div.leftimg
{
width: 150px;
float: left;
}

div.rightimg
{
width: 150px;
float: right;
}

<div id="headingcontainer">
<div class="leftimg">Left</div>
<div class="rightimg">Right</div>
<div class="heading">Content to be centered horizontally and vertically</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't quite work. Where possible I need the heading to be no more than 100px high, but the text inside could be one, two or three lines of text, so a fixed padding will not work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/KtgVN/20/

Comment: I wish I had known about this earlier. Using Firefox and firebug is okay, but this would have been easier.